# Propagate constness to data pointed by member variables

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, smart-pointers

It is often quite confusing to C++ newcomers that const member functions are allowed to call non-const methods on objects referenced by the class (either by pointer or reference). For example, the following is perfectly correct:

```
class SomeClass
{
    class SomeClassImpl;
    SomeClassImpl * impl_; // PImpl idiom

  public:    

    void const_method() const;
};

struct SomeClass::SomeClassImpl
{
    void non_const_method() { /*modify data*/ }
};

void SomeClass::const_method() const
{
    impl_->non_const_method(); //ok because impl_ is const, not *impl_
};
```

However, it would sometimes be rather handy if the constness would propagate to pointed objects (I voluntarily used the PImpl idiom because it is one of the case where I think "constness propagation" would be very useful).

When using pointers, this can easily be achieved by using some kind of smart pointer with operators overloaded on constness:

```
template < typename T >
class const_propagating_ptr
{
  public:

    const_propagating_ptr( T * ptr ) : ptr_( ptr ) {}

    T       & operator*()       { return *ptr_; }
    T const & operator*() const { return *ptr_; }

    T       * operator->()       { return ptr_; }
    T const * operator->() const { return ptr_; }

    // assignment operator (?), get() method (?), reset() method (?)
    // ...

  private:

    T * ptr_;
};
```

Now, I just need to modify `SomeClass::impl_` to be a `const_propagating_ptr<SomeClassImpl>` to obtain the wanted behavior.

So I have a few questions about this:

1. Are there some issues with constness propagation that I have overlooked?
2. If not, are there any libraries that provide classes to obtain constness propagation?
3. Wouldn't it be useful that the common smart pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr, etc.) provide some mean to obtain this behavior (for example through a template parameter)?

Comment: What if I just copy the smart-pointer? Voila, I have a non-const one.

Comment: `T const * const operator->() const { return ptr_; }` - probably no need for the second `const` here

Comment: @Alf and @robin: The sketch I gave of a possible implementation is probably littered with bugs (despite its short size :)), it is not the central point of the question. However, your feedback is really appreciated! Regarding the copy issue, I don't see at the moment how we could prevent that from being possible, but often you can't completely prevent yourself from shooting yourself in the foot (for example, you can always `const_cast` away constness, it doesn't mean that const is useless). Regarding the second comment, you are right @robin, I mistakenly did that to prevent `ptr_` from being...

Comment: [cont.] modified by the caller, which is stupid because the pointer is returned by value...I'll remove that const right away.

Comment: constness is a property of a reference, not of the referenced object.

Comment: There is now an official proposal [propagate_const](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4372.html) for C++17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As @Alf P. Steinbach noted, you oversaw the fact that copying your pointer would yield a non-const object pointing to the same underlying object. `Pimpl` (below) nicely circumvent the issue by performing a deep-copy, `unique_ptr` circumvents it by being non-copyable. It is much easier, of course, if the pointee is owned by a single entity.
2. [Boost.Optional](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/development.html) propagates const-ness, however it's not exactly a pointer (though it models the OptionalPointee concept). I know of no such other library.
3. I would favor that they provide it by default. Adding another template parameter (traits class I guess) does not seem worth the trouble. However that would radically change the syntax from a classic pointer, so I am not sure that people would be ready to embrace it.

---

Code of the `Pimpl` class

```
template <class T>
class Pimpl
{
public:
  /**
   * Types
   */
  typedef T value;
  typedef const T const_value;
  typedef T* pointer;
  typedef const T* const_pointer;
  typedef T& reference;
  typedef const T& const_reference;

  /**
   * Gang of Four
   */
  Pimpl() : _value(new T()) {}
  explicit Pimpl(const_reference v) : _value(new T(v)) {}

  Pimpl(const Pimpl& rhs) : _value(new T(*(rhs._value))) {}

  Pimpl& operator=(const Pimpl& rhs)
  {
    Pimpl tmp(rhs);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
  } // operator=

  ~Pimpl() { boost::checked_delete(_value); }

  void swap(Pimpl& rhs)
  {
    pointer temp(rhs._value);
    rhs._value = _value;
    _value = temp;
  } // swap

  /**
   * Data access
   */
  pointer get() { return _value; }
  const_pointer get() const { return _value; }

  reference operator*() { return *_value; }
  const_reference operator*() const { return *_value; }

  pointer operator->() { return _value; }
  const_pointer operator->() const { return _value; }

private:
  pointer _value;
}; // class Pimpl<T>

// Swap
template <class T>
void swap(Pimpl<T>& lhs, Pimpl<T>& rhs) { lhs.swap(rhs); }

// Not to be used with pointers or references
template <class T> class Pimpl<T*> {};
template <class T> class Pimpl<T&> {};
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to just not use the pointer directly except through two accessor functions.

```
class SomeClass
{
  private:
    class SomeClassImpl;
    SomeClassImpl * impl_; // PImpl idiom - don't use me directly!

    SomeClassImpl * mutable_impl() { return impl_; }
    const SomeClassImpl * impl() const { return impl_; }

  public:    

    void const_method() const
    {
      //Can't use mutable_impl here.
      impl()->const_method();
    }
    void non_const_method() const
    {
      //Here I can use mutable_impl
      mutable_impl()->non_const_method();
    }
};
```

Comment: This is the solution I initially tried, except that I used a nested class instance to encapsulate the pointer, in order to prevent its access from the outer class (only the getters had access thanks to friend declarations). However, this solution adds a lot of boilerplate code for each pointer for which we need const propagation. Moreover, IMHO, using the getters and setters decrease readability (properties are one of my favorite C# features :)!).

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I just found out that the [Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) does provide a const propagating pointer ([`ConstPropPtr<T>`](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00048.html)). It looks just like the one in the question, except that it also deletes the wrapped pointer in its destructor, and it is used to implement a [`Pimpl` class](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00472.html) similar to [the one proposed by @Matthieu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729820/propagate-constness-to-data-pointed-by-member-variables/4732798#4732798) (but not copyable).

Answer (score 0):

If you think it should "propagate" const-ness, then it means you don't really believe it is a **pointer** (or reference), but you believe it is a **container**: if the value is constant when the object is constant, it's because the object **contains** the value.

So copying the object copies the value, at least logically (CoW).

If you insist that it is a pointer/reference IOW that you can copy the object while sharing the contained value, then you have **an unsound (contradicting) interface**.

**Conclusion**: make up your mind. It is either a container or a pointer.

**A pointer does not propagate const-ness, *by definition*.**

Comment: I think you missed the point: even when an object is contained (owned) by another object, you sometimes need to store it using a pointer (polymorphism, lazy initialization, compilation firewall, ...). It is in these cases that const propagation would be useful: since *conceptually* the pointee is contained by the object, const methods of the object should not be allowed to modify it. However, I agree that my sample class `SomeClass` should have either defined a copy constructor or disallowed copy, to avoid accidentaly sharing `impl_` between `SomeClass`' instances.

Comment: _"I think you missed the point: you may want to propagates const_" I get that, and you missed my point: you want to propagate const-ness because you do not want **pointer** semantic. Please do not call that class `something_pointer`! "_even when an object is contained (owned) by another object, you sometimes need to store it using a pointer_" Yes, indeed.

Comment: BTW, in case someone would argue that names are not so important: if you call something a "pointer" (that does not actually have pointer semantic), some other programmer might come along and add pointer-related stuff that doesn't quite make sense for something that is not supposed to have pointer semantic. By calling it a container you (mostly) avoid this risk.

Comment: Ok, I get your point and mostly agree. I was a little confused by your use of the word "container": it could apply both to the enclosing class (`SomeClass` in the example) and to the wrapper encapsulating the data member (`const_propagating_ptr` could be renamed `container`), but I thought you wanted to apply it to the original data member (`impl_`), which did not make many sense.