# Invoking a nonconst method on a member from a const method

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, const-correctness

I was surprised to find this "hole" in "const"ness:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
  int r ;
public:
  A():r(0){}

  void nonconst()
  {
    puts( "I am in ur nonconst method" ) ;
    r++;
  }
} ;

class B
{
  A a ;
  A* aPtr ;

public:
  B(){ aPtr = new A() ; }

  void go() const
  {
    //a.nonconst() ;      // illegal
    aPtr->nonconst() ;  //legal
  }
} ;

int main()
{
  B b ;
  b.go() ;
}
```

So basically from `const` method `B::go()`, you can invoke the *non-const* member function (aptly named `nonconst()`) if object of type `A` is referenced by a pointer.

Why is that?  Seems like a problem (it kind of was in my code, where I found it.)

Comment: This is rather unexpected. I ran it through g++ 4.2.1 on a Mac, and the code compiled (much to my surprise). I'm curious to see the answer to this.

Comment: This behavior is often surprising the first time you stumble upon it. Some time ago, I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4729820/20984) to know if there were solutions for propagating constness to pointee objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When and object of type `B` is const, then all of its members are const, which means its two members are, for the duration of `B::go()`, effectively

```
A const a;
A * const aPtr;
```

The first is a constant object of type `A`, on which you can only call const member functions.  The second, however, is a constant pointer to a non-constant `A`.  You could not legally say `aPtr = <anything>` from within the function `B::go()`, since that would modify `aPtr`, which is constant.

A pointer to a constant `A` would be declared as `A const* aPtr` or `const A* aPtr`, which would then make calling the non-constant `A::nonconst()` illegal.

Comment: Ah, very clever answer. Pedantic.

Answer (score 6):

The "const-ness" of an object does *not* extend to other objects through pointers. In your example, the `const` part is either the entire object `a`, or the *pointer* `aPtr`. Because `aPtr` is a `A *` and not a `const A *`, you are allowed to call a non-const method.

If you change

```
A* aPtr ;
```

to

```
const A* aPtr ;
```

then you will not be able to call `aPtr->nonconst()`.

Comment: Hmm.. that would render the object `A` nearly useless if you ever need to use it's non-const facilities.  I thought marking a method `const` is a contract not to change state information of the object... I thought __all__ members should get marked `const`, even the ptrs!  I had a `dirty` bit that got set whenever a non-const method was invoked.  But now, even some `const` methods should set the dirty bit!  What a surprise.

Comment: When an object is `const`, all its members are `const` also. You cannot change what `aPtr` points to inside a `const` method. However, your current object being `const` doesn't affect the `const`-ness of any *other* object.

Comment: @bobobobo "_I thought all members should get marked const_" Yes, and they are, of course. That does not make other objects const, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

## Language definition of `const`

> I was surprised to find this "hole" in "const"ness:

There is none.

`const` applies **uniformly** to all class members: in a `const` member function of class `C`, `this` has type `const C *`, so for a member `C::mem` declared as type `T`:

```
class C {
// ...
    T mem;
};
```

`this->mem` has type `const T`.

Please take type to discern what is the declared type `T` and the corresponding const-qualified type for all the members.

> Seems like a problem (it kind of was in my code, where I found it.)

Just because the *systematic application of rules* does not do what you expected does not mean there is a problem with the rules, it means there is a problem with your expectations.

You should write down your expectations to see that you expected a non uniform application if `const` to different types.

When you program, you have to reason logically. You should infer things, not expect them when there is no logical reason.

## Using `const` correctly

> Why is that?

Your classes being called `A` and `B`, it's pretty hard to understand what constitute logical state and what does not. ;) You ask a "moral" question (not a question only on legal/illegal C++ programs), and your code fragment has no "moral" value. If you actually post relevant code, we might make some "moral" judgements about it.

### Logical state

You should declare `const` the functions that do not change the "logical state" of the object it's applied to.

It means **you have to define what is the "logical state" of your class instances**: it's an abstract concept, and only you can define it, because it's a high level concept. **The "logical state" relates to the problem your class should solve.**

Then you can discern which variables contribute to the logical state: does `*(b.aPtr)` contribute to the logical state of `b`?

### Closely related questions

Do you know about the copy constructor?

About the copy assignment operator?

About the destructor?

Comment: Really, it would help if the downvoter could add some kind of explanation.