# Why can reference members be modified by const member functions?

Tags: c++

The following will [compile](http://ideone.com/eyLe9A) even though a const member function will modify the value of a member. How so ?

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    std::string &str;
    foo(std::string &other) : str(other) {}

    void operator()(std::string &some) const
    {
        str += some;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string ext("Hello");
    foo a{ ext };

    std::string more(" world!");
    a(more);

    cout << a.str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It modifies what the member refers to, it does not modify the member.

Comment: Because it won't modify the reference itself. After applying the `+=` operator, the reference does not change, only the internal string contents do (in the context of the string, `this` is still the same).

Comment: Try it with std::string* instead of & and you'll see the same thing.

Comment: It's called bitwise `const`, which is what C++ enforces, as opposed to logical `const`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830367) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556794).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const` qualifier of a class member function indicates that this member function (e.g., `foo::operator() const`) cannot change the state of the object from the *client's point of view* (i.e., it's abstract state). This is not exactly the same as saying that the object's *raw bits* are not going to change.

It is forbitten to C++ compilers to consider objects as raw bits, unless they can resolve [the problem of aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing). which in your case the compiler cannot. This is due to the fact that a non-constant alias exists (i.e., `std::string &str`) and consequently the state of the object is modifiable.

That is, calling `operator()` on object `a` does not change the state of `a` (i.e., although `ext` has changed, the `str` still remains an alias of `ext`).

The above also explains why pointing at an object with a pointer to constant (i.e., `std::string * const str`) does not guarantee that the object won't be modified. It only guarantees that the object won't change through that pointer.

Answer (score 12):

Consider the reference like a classic pointer:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    std::string * const str; // is the same as std::string &str
    foo(std::string &other) : str(&other) {}

    void operator()(std::string &some) const
    {
        *str += some;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string ext("Hello");
    foo a{ ext };

    std::string more(" world!");
    a(more);

    cout << a.str;
    return 0;
}
```

You'll see that the pointer doesn't change, only the value pointed by it does.