# Does a class with all attributes const need to have member function declared const as well?

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes, constants, member-functions

The title already says all. Let me expand a little nevertheless: I've class whose all attributes are `const`:

```
template< class perm  = Perm16 >
class PermutationGroup {
public:
  using StrongGeneratingSet = std::vector< std::vector< perm > >;

  const std::string name;
  const uint64_t N;
  const StrongGeneratingSet sgs;
  PermutationGroup(std::string name, uint64_t N, StrongGeneratingSet sgs) :
      name(name), N(N), sgs(sgs) { assert(check_sgs()); };

  bool check_sgs() const;            // defined as const
  bool is_canonical(vect v) const;   // defined as const

  [...]

};
```

Is it of any use to define all member function as `const` as well ? Or am I needlessly repeating myself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not declare the member functions as *const*, you can't invoke them on *const* objects or objects referenced by a *const reference*. For example, the following won't work:

```
const PermutationGroup& group = PermutationGroup("foobar", 42, ...);
group.check_sgs(); // ERROR: can't invoke non-const function on const objects
```

Comment: Good point ! This raise the following followup question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449773/it-there-a-need-to-declare-const-instance-of-a-class-with-all-attributes-const

Answer (score 0):

Declaring your methods as `const` means that you can call them on a `const`-qualified object. It's not necessary to declare them `const` just because there are no mutable fields in the class, but in general, it's easier to write const-correct code if you always declare methods that don't modify anything as `const`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a class with all attributes const need to have member function declared const as well?

Declaring a member variable `const` is different than declaring a member function `const`. When a member variable is declared `const` it cannot be modified. It can still be accessed by member functions even those not declared `const`, they just can't be modified.

Decalring a member function `const` is saying this function does not modify this object. The function is not allowed to change any member variable unless it's declared `mutable`. It also cannot call member functions that are not declared `const` as those functions would be allowed to modify the object.

Declaring member functions as `const` is important as it allows those functions to be called on constant instances of the class they belong to. Nosid provides a great example in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23449626/845568).

Comment: `you cast away it's constness with const_cast` will invoke undefined behavior, won't it ?

Comment: @hivert Attempting to modify a non-mutable object will result in UB. Even including that was a poor decision on my part ;)

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.

That been said, constness on behalf of the attributes implies constness on behalf of the instance, so even if a member function is **non const** it won't be able to behave as such (ie cause state mutation)

The other way around is not true though. For example

```
int myClass::example() const {
    member = 1;
}
```

is the same as

```
int myClass::example() const {
    this->member = 1;
}
```

and constness of the member function means constness of `this` pointer. This is slightly different from promising that the "raw bits" of the object's struct aren't going to change. For example, [reference members can be modified by `const` member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23436836/2567683)

To sum up : Declaring a member function as `const` becomes mandatory when it's to be used with a `this` pointer that is `const`. In your case, not declaring one as `const` would just be futile (and break the inspector / mutator semantics .. that being less of a deal).