# Why can use << in const function body?

Tags: c++, constants, operator-keyword, ostream

const function body can't change members of class.The operator << will change the ostream object, if the ostream object is a member.

this is example in C++ primer(5th edition):

```
class PrintString{
public:
    PrintString(ostream &o = cout, char c = ' '):
        os(o), sep(c)  {} 
    void operator()(const string &s) const { os << s << sep; }
private:
    ostream &os;
    char sep;
};
```

why can write like "const {os << s << sep;}"? Does the operator << change the os?

Comment: Are you saying `os << s << sep;` works, or doesn't work? It seems like there is at least one missing "not" somewhere in this question.

Answer (score 1):

All that `const` is ensuring is your function cannot change the object pointed to by `this`. It doesn't say anything about whether you can call `const` members on `os` itself or not. The semantics you are looking for would be if it was declared like `ostream& const os;`.

Comment: If I defined: ostream &os = cout;  The sentence "os << something; " just change the "cout", do not change the os, right?

Comment: `os` is a reference, to `cout`. Anything done to one will be visible through the other. I don't fully understand what you are asking.

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/q/23436836/13316448 solves my problem. Sorry about my poor English and thank you for your time. I need to learn how to ask questions more clearly.