# Does this violate the rules of const?

Tags: c++

a simple piece of code：

```
class HasPtr
{
public:
    HasPtr(const string& s = string()) :ps(new string(s)), i(0), use(new size_t(1)) {}
    HasPtr(const HasPtr& p) :ps(p.ps), i(p.i), use(p.use) { ++* use; }
    HasPtr& operator=(const HasPtr&);
    ~HasPtr();
private:
    string* ps;
    int i;
    size_t* use;
};

HasPtr& HasPtr::operator=(const HasPtr& rhs)
{
    ++* rhs.use;
    if (-- * use == 0) {
        delete ps;
        delete use;
    }
    ps = rhs.ps;
    i = rhs.i;
    use = rhs.use;
    return *this;
}
```

The parameter of the copy assignment operator is const.c++ primer says **A const type can use most but not all of the same operations as its nonconst version.The one restriction is that we may use only those operations that cannot an object.** Why can the value pointed to by use(++* rhs.use) be modified here? Does this violate the rules for const properties?

Comment: `++* rhs.use;` don't write code like this.

Comment: You're missing `if (this != &rhs)`

Comment: The operator may handle self-assignment.

Comment: If `ps` is a `const` pointer you cannot change `ps`. But there's nothing that prevents you from changing whatever `ps` points to. A pointer, and the object the pointer is pointing to, are two completely independent things. Either one can be `const`, on its own merits.

Comment: `p.use` is `const` and you can't change it, the value it points to isn't `const` so can be changed

Comment: Here, `use` is not modifed, so the technically there is no violation of the const correctness. If fact, it depends on does `*use` correspond to a designated item, or an included item.

Comment: And in the second case, it is clearly a problem, but may can caracterise the pointer see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729820/propagate-constness-to-data-pointed-by-member-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The members of `const` class are `const`. The const version of `size_t*` is

```
size_t* const use;
```

Which is a constant pointer of size_t to non-constant object `use`. You cannot change what the pointer points to, but when you dereference the pointer you get non-const object, which you can modify.

Answer (score 1):

> why can the value pointed to by use(++* rhs.use) be modified?

`use` is a pointer to non-const, so it is well-formed to modify through it. In this case, it points to a non-const dynamic object, so modifying the pointed object is well-defined.

> Does this violate the rules for const properties?

No.